# log4j2 fails to write to file

Tags: java, wicket, log4j2, tomcat8

Ideally, I would like to log everything during development on a localhost and to log only errors on the live server. I am having trouble logging to files on my development platform (Windows 10, Java with Wicket).

log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/articles.html
http://mycuteblog.com/log4j2-xml-configuration-example/ -->
<Configuration status="DEBUG">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="log-path">${sys:catalina.home}/logs</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="console-log" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
        <RollingFile name="trace-log" fileName="${log-path}/luminous-trace.log"
            filePattern="${log-path}/luminous-trace-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
        <RollingFile name="error-log" fileName="${log-path}/luminous-error.log"
            filePattern="${log-path}/luminous-error-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="com.linguaclassica" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="trace-log" level="debug"/>
            <appender-ref ref="error-log" level="error"/>
            <appender-ref ref="console-log" level="debug"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="info" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="console-log"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

I have managed to get some logs written to my tomcat's `logs` folder.

Only some of my messages are appearing. I do not know what symbols are significant and what are not.

The base page for publicly accessable pages logs the subclass.

```
public class PublicBasePage extends WebPage
{
    protected static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(PublicBasePage.class);

    public PublicBasePage()
    {
        super();

        logger.info(this.getClass().getName());
    }
}
```

> [INFO ] 2017-10-19 17:07:13.208 [http-nio-8080-exec-57] PublicBasePage
>   - com.linguaclassica.access.HomePage
>   The base page for the private web pages logs a message.

```
public class PrivateBasePage extends WebPage
{
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(PrivateBasePage.class);

    public PrivateBasePage()
    {
        super();

        logger.debug("()");
    }
}
```

> [DEBUG] 2017-10-19 17:12:05.662 [http-nio-8080-exec-62]
>   PrivateBasePage - ()

However, messages for the private page do not get logged to a file or to the console.

```
public class ClientLandingPage extends PrivateBasePage
{
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(ClientLandingPage.class);

    public ClientLandingPage()
    {
        super();    

        logger.info("(info)");
        logger.debug("(debug)");
        logger.warn("(warn)");
    }
}
```

I do not understand what is failing.

Comment: when your app log4j loads its settings it does some sysout. can you check them and post them.

Comment: In which package, `ClientLandingPage` and other classes are present ?

Comment: ClientLandingPage is in folder com.linguaclassica.client. There are three other folders for other user roles plus one for shared roles.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this was careless. ClientLandingPage is obsolete and was never called, being replaced by shared/CommonOverviewPage. I changed the declarations to

```
private Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(SomethingPage.class);
```

and the logs seem to come out as I want them.

Yesterday's logs have the date appended to the file name.